# Why chaincode instantiate success, but query failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
peer chaincode install -n simple-token -v 1.0 -l java -p /Users/friends/Documents/Virtual\ Machines.localized/share/projects/hsl-hsl-user-guide-examples-v14/simple-token/simple-token-chaincode
```

peer chaincode instantiate successed.

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer:7050 -C helloch  -n simple-token -v 1.0 -l java -c "{\"Args\":[\"init\",\"{'id':'admin1','nick':'admin','type':'ADMIN','balance':100}\", \"{'id':'LiLei','nick':'LiLei','type':'ORDINARY','balance':100}\", \"{'id':'HanMeimei','nick':'HanMeimei','type':'ORDINARY','balance':100}\"]}"
```

but failed in peer chaincode query in my shell not cli docker,Why?
Actually ,

```
peer chaincode query -o 127.0.0.1:7050 -C helloch -n  hello -c "{\"Args\":[\"user.get\",\"\",\"LiLei\"]}"
```

> Error: Error endorsing query: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = could not find chaincode with name 'simple-token' - make sure the chaincode simple-token has been successfully instantiated and try again - hy

Comment: Can you run "docker ps" to see whenever your chaincode container is running? Or docker "ps -a | grep -i hello" and then "docker logs containerID" to see the output?

Comment: Based on logs provided within your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045970/why-peer-chaincode-instantiate-execuate-many-times-successfully it seems that peer simply cannot fetch block with instantiate transaction, hence chaincode container is not spanned and therefore you are not able to query your chaincode.

Answer (score 1):

Described behavior could be due to the fact that peer is not able to get the block with instantiate command. The instantiate command after all is a transaction which has to be endorsed, ordered and committed. What probably confuses you is the fact that peer cli succeeded to endorse instantiate transaction and submit it to the ordering service. While it might not be committed, hence chaincode container not started and as a result you are not able to query your chaincode.

Comment: Yeah,  It has been solved.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045970/why-peer-chaincode-instantiate-execuate-many-times-successfully/46048140#46048140),thank you!

Comment: I am in a similar - but weirder - situation: the chaincode container is started, submits the REGISTER request to the peer, _which the peer acknowledges_, but then the instantiated code is not listed in `peer chaincode list --instantiated -C mycnannel`

Comment: I've managed to turn that comment into a full-fledged question
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735065/chaincode-is-instantiated-but-doesnt-appear-in-the-list-of-instantiated-codes

Answer (score 0):

Likely something went wrong when the peer actually tried to start / launch the chaincode.  The instantiate call simply creates a transaction which is sent to back to the peer via the orderer.  So while the CLI indicated success, all that really means is that the instantiate transaction was successfully endorsed by the peer and then successfully submitted to the orderer.

You'll want to check the actual logs for your peer.

Comment: It seems that `peer chaincode instantiate` does not generate the instance. Because I can use this command many times.  only once is correct. could u tell me some reasoms for instantiate failing ?

Comment: It's usually either either an issue compiling the chaincode or the other issue is that the chaincode container cannot communicate with the peer.  You should be able to see errors in the log(s) of your actually peer(s)

Comment: I think the reason is instantiate failed.

Comment: Oh - just noticed something - if you are using the standard images from Dockerhub, then Java chaincode support is disabled

Comment: We changed the fabric source code, make it support java

Comment: The logs is very long , is there ways to copy the content?

Comment: I'd just search the logs locally and look for Error

Comment: [my problem description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045970/why-peer-chaincode-instantiate-execuate-many-times-successfully/46047171#46047171) , there is the logs.