# Why peer chaincode instantiate execuate many times successfully

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I could execute `peer chaincode instantiate` many times successfully,  it should returns it exist, but no.  why?

[logs after instantiate command](https://github.com/friends110110/chaincode-docker-devmode/blob/master/instantiatelogs.txt)

[logs the docker returns](https://github.com/friends110110/chaincode-docker-devmode/blob/master/log.txt)

**steps**:

from [my github project chaincode-docker-devmode](https://github.com/friends110110/chaincode-docker-devmode/tree/master), I copy msp (peer and orderer use together) 、genesis.block、helloch.tx、docker-compose-with-couch.yaml and so on form other place,it should be ok. When I execute :

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-with-couch.yaml up
```

peer、orderer、couchdb0、cli start  and then cli execute script.sh

```
#script.sh content
peer channel create -c helloch -f helloch.tx -o orderer:7050
peer channel join -b helloch.block
```

then I simulate cli enviroment using terminal at chaincode-docker-devmode current path by following:

```
#cli simulation, $pwd  is the chaincode-docker-devmode path
export CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/run/docker.sock
export CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
export CORE_PEER_ID=cli
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DEFAULT
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$pwd/msp
bash
```

When I execute `peer channel list` It could shows I have join **helloch**

channel. Then I execute :

```
peer chaincode install -n hello -v 1.0 -l java -p chaincode/hsl-hsl-user-guide-examples-v14/mytest
peer chaincode instantiate -o 127.0.0.1:7050 -C helloch  -n hello -v 1.0 -l java -c "{\"Args\":[\"init\",\"a\", \"100\", \"b\",\"100\"]}"
```

But I can instantiate many times and the log does not return error [as same as above instantiate logs](https://github.com/friends110110/chaincode-docker-devmode/blob/master/instantiatelogs.txt), actually it does not instantiate successfully, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiate of the chaincode is essentially a transaction, therefore it has to be endorsed, ordered and committed to take effect. Now in your case peer cli instantiate command succeeds since the transaction proposal successfully endorsed and signed proposal submitted to the ordering service. While based on the following log output:

```
peer        | 2017-09-05 01:09:23.650 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 6da Failed connecting to 127.0.0.1:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
peer        | 2017-09-05 01:09:23.650 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 6db Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [127.0.0.1:7050]
```

Peer cannot get connected to the ordering service endpoint which in your case configured to be `127.0.0.1:7050`, therefore eventually instantiate transaction is not committed. Therefore you do able to execute the instantiate command again, since no instantiate transaction record exists on the peer ledger from your previous attempt.

You need to change ordering service endpoint from `127.0.0.1:7050` to `orderer:7050` and retry your experiment. This value configured inside `configtx.yaml` file, e.g.:

```
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer:7050
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You are right ! I am very exciting.

Comment: Welcome :) and I believe this also solves your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035198/why-chaincode-instantiate-success-but-query-failed

Comment: Yeah, they are the same problems. Thank you, we can communicate and can I have your email?

Comment: Find me on Rocket.Chat, chat.hyperledger.org, @C0rWin.

Comment: error  instaitate the chaincode:- Peer logs  :-  [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 095 [mychannel][0e6974c0] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
 /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
 /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333 chaincode registration failed
ON CLI :-  Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0

Comment: @ArtemBarger can you please guide me I am still having the same problem. I have made changes in the file as you have mentioned (Addresses:
         - orderer:7050) but still the same error.  (Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode fabcar not found")

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this was giving me trouble because I did not give the instantiation process enough time before calling an invoke/query transaction.

Try adding a sleep command between your instantiate and invoke/query transaction:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -l "$LANGUAGE" -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"

# Sleeping to allow time for chaincode to instantiate on peers
sleep 30

peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[""]}'
```

This only applies in the case that you are running a "startup" script in a CLI container of some sort.  In my case, I have `script.sh` which runs when I first bring the network up.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a chaincode with same name only once.

Comment: I know only one, but from my examples, I instantiate many times and docker logs do not return error message. I support instantiate does not success.But I can not find reasons? Could you watch the logs I add above and help me to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
peer channel create -c helloch -f helloch.tx -o 127.0.0.1:7050
```

after above, you could see the helloch.block detail message  by command

```
configtxgen --inspectBlock helloch.block
```

It shows

```
"OrdererAddresses": {
                "Version": "0",
                "ModPolicy": "/Channel/Orderer/Admins",
                "Value": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "127.0.0.1:7050"
                    ]
                }
            },
```

it seems that the connected orderer address which in helloch.block(channel configuration) comes from genesis.block (which generate from configtx.yaml )