# chaincode instantiate: Error reading from ip:port; rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled. without docker

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a network of hyperledger fabric, with one orderer and one peer, orderer in orderer organization(OrdererOrg) and peer in peer organization (Org1). I am able to start both orderer and peer, create a channel and peer is able to join the channel.

Next, I am able to install the chaincode on the peer node. However, when I try to instantiate the chaincode, on the orderer terminal I am getting WARN message

> 2019-04-25 16:48:08.203 EDT [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 01a Error reading from 127.0.0.1:33340: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

On peer terminal and executing terminal, there is no error message, and it shows that the command ran successfully.

The `instantiate` is able to download the docker container for the chaincode.

I can see the docker images by running `docker image ls`, it shows two docker images

> myfn-peer1-mycc-1.0-6ec0d4e71b402887d447e77b3b23b0ab860673e40ec5750a912a2faffe0158cf
>
> hyperledger/fabric-javaenv

Next, when I try to query the chain code, I get error saying chaincode not found.

```
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
```

> Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode mycc has been successfully instantiated and try again: chaincode mycc not found"

I am not sure what is missing, I have checked the configs and environment variables and all seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, your Peer is able to create instantiate transaction and send it to the orderer. Orderer, on the other hand, creates a block and send it to the peer. However, the peer is not able to get the block and store it in the ledger, in this case, you will be able to instantiate your chaincode again and again. And if you try to query you will get

> Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode mycc has been successfully instantiated and try again: chaincode mycc not found"

Artem Barger mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46048140/5361492), however, in this answer you **don't** need to set ordering service endpoint to `orderer.7050`.

The solution to this problem is, the orderer uses gossip protocol to send the blocks to its peers. Make sure in your config you have properly set the gossip protocol (`core.peer.gossip`).

```
peer:
    gossip:
        bootstrap: 127.0.0.1:7051
        externalEndpoint: 127.0.0.1:7051
        useLeaderElection: true
        orgLeader: false
```

This should solve the problem.