# Chaincode is instantiated but doesn't appear in the list of instantiated codes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am running Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.0

I have 1 org (`Org1`), 2 peers (`peer0`, `peer1`) and two orderers (`ord0`, `ord1`). The peers use `couchdb` as a storage backend.

I am able to successfully `install` my chaincode, then `instantiate` it.

Looking at `peer0` logs, the docker image is built and the container started. `peer0` also receives and acknowledges the `REGISTER` request sent by the `chaincode` binary within the container:

```
2019-06-24 10:15:57.003 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU b563 created container {"imageID": "nid1-peer0-mynet-mychain-v1-613158e6e99c2c9e7d567e8b57fe2dfb56444f7fdcbc263dd1f61626a374843d", "containerID": "nid1-peer0-mynet-mychain-v1"}
2019-06-24 10:15:57.160 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU b564 Started container nid1-peer0-mynet-mychain-v1
2019-06-24 10:15:57.160 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU b565 container lock deleted(mychain-v1)
2019-06-24 10:15:57.181 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU b566 [] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTER in state created
2019-06-24 10:15:57.181 UTC [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU b567 Received REGISTER in state created
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] Register -> DEBU b568 registered handler complete for chaincode mychain:v1
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU b569 Got REGISTER for chaincodeID = name:"mychain:v1" , sending back REGISTERED
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU b56a Changed state to established for name:"mychain:v1"
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] sendReady -> DEBU b56b sending READY for chaincode name:"mychain:v1"
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] sendReady -> DEBU b56c Changed to state ready for chaincode name:"mychain:v1"
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU b56d launch complete
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU b56e Entry
2019-06-24 10:15:57.182 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU b56f [1a98f442] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
```

Despite this, the chaincode is not registered in couchdb:

```
$ peer chaincode list --instantiated -C mychannel
2019-06-24 11:26:29.317 BST [main] InitCmd -> WARN 001 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
2019-06-24 11:26:29.332 BST [main] SetOrdererEnv -> WARN 002 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
Get instantiated chaincodes on channel mychannel:
```

`peer0` logs immediately after submitting the list command:

```
2019-06-24 10:26:30.057 UTC [couchdb] ReadDocRange -> DEBU c02e [mychannel_lscc] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 10:26:30 GMT
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/18)
X-Couch-Request-Id: 20d0beb9c3
X-Couchdb-Body-Time: 0

2a
{"total_rows":0,"offset":0,"rows":[

]}

0
```

If I try to invoke a method on the chaincode, I get this error:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode mychain has been successfully instantiated and try again: chaincode mychain not found"
```

which just confirms that the chaincode has not been registered within the network.

**Update**

I realised I had missed an important detail: the peer logs repeatedly report errors connecting to the orderer, e.g.:

```
2019-06-24 11:30:35.931 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 100e6 Failed connecting to ord0.mynet.example.com , error: context deadline exceeded
```

which might be the reason why the "chaincode instantiated" message doesn't get propagated...

Comment: When the chaincode is successfully instantiated it should be created as an independent container. If you run `docker ps -a` you should be able to see the chaincode, otherwise it means that the `instantiate` command didn't work. The chaincode must be installed in all the peers that are endorsers.

Comment: Yes, we can see both the docker images and the containers running.
It looks like the problem was related to a miscommunication between the peers and the orderers.

Answer (score 1):

After much debugging, it turned out the issue was pretty simple: the peers could not communicate with the orderers.

In my particular case the addresses of the orderers were wrong in `configtx.yaml`. Fixing them resulted in the chaincode instantiation process tu fully succeed.

Comment: In my case it was just recreatig the channel and redeploying the chaincode