# Problem while configuring hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am quite new to Hyperledger Fabric. I have strictly followed all [Prerequisites](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/prereqs.html) in addition to other steps to run the [test-network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#before-you-begin). I am facing the following error:

**

> (Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500
> message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined
> on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode fabcar not found" ).

**
As inquired, the version of hyperledger fabric is as follows:
[image: version details.]

Please note that the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035198/why-chaincode-instantiate-success-but-query-failed) did not solve my problem. Furthermore, digging more on it I also note that I can not get any response if I try to check `peer chaincode list --installed` . I even tried the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045970/why-peer-chaincode-instantiate-execuate-many-times-successfully) but its not working. Kindly please guide me.

Comment: I'm presuming chaincode installation when you're saying installing Hyperledger Fabric. Please tell which version of Fabric are you using.

Comment: Hi @KartikChauhan Thank you. I have installed all prerequisites and then I have created channel and deployed contract...when I try to query I get another error (Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode fabcar not found" ). P.S I am following the tutorial (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html). I came across some solutions too but I can not see any accepted answer. I hope I dont have to make another thread for that.

Comment: Yes @KartikChauhan, version: 2.2.0 (I hope I have checked it correctly: peer version)

Comment: I can include logs as well if it is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Kartik's question, are you using the test network to get started?  If not, I would start with the [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html) first and if you get stuck, share the logs and we will do our best to help.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the link. I have followed it. I am using Ver 2.2.0. I am now having this error: (Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode fabcar not found" ).